# Angular datepicker - how to display the selected date in a modal?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have to display the selected day from datepicker in a modal.

The div for the datepicker:

```
<div class="row" id="exDateTime" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <!--<label class="control-label">Date picker</label>-->
            <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dt">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/col-->
</div><!--/row-->
```

For display the selected value I use the following controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);



       app.controller('ctrlTags', function($scope, $uibModal, $log){

       $scope.open = function() {
           var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
               templateUrl: 'myModl.html',
               controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
               resolve: {
                   param: function () {
                       return $scope.dt;;
                   }
               }
           });
       };

       $scope.ok = function() {
           $scope.showModal = false;
       };

       $scope.cancel = function() {
           $scope.showModal = false;
       };
    });
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, param) {

        $scope.inputValue = param;

        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });
```

The selected date is not displayed in the modal

Comment: Is `$scope.getFormattedDate` defined somewhere else?

Comment: We don't know your scope hierarchy. Check first if `$scope.getFormattedDate($scope.dt)` is defined in the resolver, which seems it's not. Also, you can remove your `ok` and `cancel` function from `ctrlTags`

Comment: @Michael P. Bazos- I edited the code. I don't use getFormattedDate. I just want to return the selected date

Comment: What does `$log.log($scope.dt)` output? Place that before returning `$scope.dt` in the resolver.

Comment: @Michael P. Bazos Tue Oct 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (IDT)

Comment: @Michael P. Bazos - shouldn't I just display in the modal {{dt}}?

Comment: If `dt` is in the scope of the modal yes, don't bother passing it through a resolver.

Comment: @Michael P. Bazos- well...it doesn't work. May be because the modal is in different html file?